# How to group the table in the following way?

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, data, gathering, table

Consider the following table:

```
tabb = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 1, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 16}, {5, 6, 7, 9}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 16}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 16, 13, 35}, {1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 16, 13, 35}, {1, 1, 14, 8, 33, 8, 13, 35}};
```

Could you please tell me how to group it by the number of columns and also the product of each second column?

I.e., the rows `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 1, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 9},{5, 6, 7, 8}}` of `tabb` have the same number of columns, but the products of the 2nd and 4th columns are different. Therefore, they should be considered as different elements: the first two rows form one element, while the remaining two form another two elements.

I probably should use `GroupGy[tabb,{Length,condition}]` where `condition` specifies the product of the columns. My problem is that I cannot generalize the condition to an arbitrary number of columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) takes as the second argument an arbitrary function which can serve as a "grouping parameter". As you have correctly identified it, you can use a list `{length, product}` as a parameter. To get every second element of a list, use [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html).

```
GroupBy[tabb, {Length[#], Times @@ #[[2 ;; ;; 2]]} &]

(* <| {4, 8} -> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 1, 7, 8}}, 
      {6, 128} -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 13, 16}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 16}}, 
      {4, 54} -> {{5, 6, 7, 9}}, 
      {4, 48} -> {{5, 6, 7, 8}}, 
      {8, 4480} -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 11, 16, 13, 35}}, 
      {8, 2240} -> {{1, 1, 3, 4, 11, 16, 13, 35}, {1, 1, 14, 8, 33, 8, 13, 35}}|> *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you please tell me what is the meaning of the symbols inside the bracket in `#[[2 ;; ;; 2]]`?

Comment: It is a shorter syntax for [`Span`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html), namely `Span[2, All, 2]` which means "start at the second element of the list, go through the whole list, taking every 2nd element".

Comment: Or, if you just want lists, use `GatherBy` instead of `GroupBy`